# PDF viewer in my iOS app is blank. Any ideas?

Tags: ios, pdf, uiwebview, xcode4.5

I am using a UIWebView do display a PDF inside my application. I am using this to load the PDF from the supporting files and display it.

```
NSString *urlAddress = [[NSString alloc] init];

urlAddress = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MyFile" ofType:@"pdf"];

NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:urlAddress];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[self.pdfWebView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

When I run the application, the UIWebView is blank.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your MyFile.pdf is not included in the bundle. If you run it on the simulator you can browse to your simulators App and right click show content. Check with `[[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:url]`.